# MVC Razor runtime compilation, how long are the compilations preserved?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an Asp.Net MVC 5 Application. A specific page includes a lot of views.
If I open the page for the first time, the command line compiler is running about 4 minutes. After that the page loads in 1-2 seconds.

My question is, how long will my compiled views be preserved? Is it until a pool recyle or only if a view does change? Where is the location of these compiled files?

Regards

Comment: Check out this tutorial where it shows you to precompile the views when you deploy so the server doesn't have to: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/compile-your-asp-net-mvc-views/

Comment: RE: your question, yes, usually when the application pool recycles, is when stuff gets slow again. I experience it every 24 hours or so